# getting the value of an array of object in handlebar

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm working with expressJS and handlebar as an engine template in my index.hbs I have a JS script in which I need to get a value of an array of object, here is the code of my script

```
  <script >

    new Morris.Line({
    element: 'myfirstchart',
    parseTime:false,

     data: {{graph}},
     xkey: 'version',
    ykeys: ['success'],

 labels: ['Success']
    });

    </script>
```

but the array graph does not pass, in my log console it is shown like 
this[image]

What should I do to get the value of my {{graph}} ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add a sample of your data in {{graph}} and also what you expect instead of [object Object]. You'll need to format your data with the handlebar template {{graph}} contains one array of 5 elements containing objects.

If your data is let say {'x': '100', 'y':200} and that you want the same output with handlebar then you should put this instead of {{graph}}:

```
[{{#each graph}}{'x': {{x}}, 'y': {{y}} }{{/each}}]
```

If you put your data and the expected output format I'll may give a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify your array object i.e. JSON.stringify(graph) from server side and while accessing it use triple brackets **{{{graph}}}** in your javascript script tag code.